# Graphing the set $ (1,2) \cup [3,5] \times (1,2) \cup [3,5]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graphing-functions, relations

Question:

Graph the set $  (1,2) \cup [3,5] \times  (1,2) \cup [3,5]$

My attempt:

[image]

I am new to graphing theses kinds of sets. I attempted to draw this one. I am not quite sure if I graphed it correctly. If I am wrong could someone please tell me my mistake?

Comment: Seems perfect to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt is correct!

The first statement says that $x$ must lie in the range of $(1,2)$ **OR** $(3,5)$, which makes two *vertical strips* in the range of $y= ]-\infty, \infty[$.

The second statement says that $y$ must lie in the range of $(1,2)$ **OR** $(3,5)$, which similarly makes two *horizontal* strips from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ like before.

The $×$ sign is equivalent to the **AND** symbol, which shows the *overlap* between the horizontal and vertical rectangles.

Nice job!